# One common registration for all sites or separate registration for each site?

Tags: authentication, authorization

I am currently developing a website and will be implementing a registration system on it, and I plan to develop another project (website and program) in the future, which will also require authorization. So I have a question that I can't give a clear answer to. Do I do one general registration for all sites (for example, like Google, Apple or Nord Security), or do I do a separate registration for each site and product?